# How to close an ngbactive modal programatically without the modal being closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, bootstrap-modal

Table-component.ts

```
openModal(rowData: any = null) {
const config: Partial<DynamicFormComponent> = {
    form: this.form,
    data: rowData
};

const options: NgbModalOptions = { size: 'sm', centered: true };

const modalRef = this.ModalService.show((DynamicFormComponent), config, options)
```

}

dynamic-form.html

```
 constructor(
  private activeModal: NgbActiveModal
 ){}

onSubmit(){this.activeModal.close(this.dynamicFodmGroup.value) //here the modal is closing but i dont want that
  }
```

The show method returns an observable which is triggered when modal is closed. How to achieve the same without closing the modal?

Please help :(
Many thanks